# Можно ли узнать версию composer и fxp?

Tags: composer

Как понять какой fxp/composer-asset-plugin установлен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В консоли выполните команду

```
composer global show
```

Answer (score 1):

в принципе можно зайти в composer.lock и найти там данный плагин